# Normalizing boolean expressions (using Prolog)

Tags: prolog

I have trouble normalizing a series of logical predicates

Suppose we have two non-overlapping time-periods:

......ta1_____ta2.....tb1______tb2......

In order for the timeperiods to be legal, non-overlapping and ordered a->b, the following facts can be observed:

ta1 < ta2

tb1 < tb2

ta1 < tb1

ta1 < tb2

ta2 <= tb1

ta2 < tb2

However its easy to see one fact is sufficient:

ta2 <= tb1

Is there a mathematical construct for normalizing all known facts to the single sufficient fact?

Eventually I want to program that kind of reasoning in Prolog, so any pointers in that direction would be awesome to!

Comment: Are only less than (or equal) predicates given? Because in general normalizing a program is undecidable...

Comment: And furthermore more is necessary: you also need to verify that `ta1 < ta2` and `tb1 < tb2`... You simply assume this is possible.

Comment: You're right: ta1 < ta2 and tb1 < tb2 cannot be ignored.

Comment: Well not necessary: you can set them as preconditions. (additional precondition is that `TA1 < TB1`... I answered with an outline of such algorithm. Is this sufficient?

Comment: May be you can take a look at Constraint Handling Rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to normalize this, you need a set of less than (or equal) tuples as well as a set of such constraints you see as assumptions: constraints that should hold, but does not need to be checked.

This means the input should be something like:

```
normalize([TA1<TA2,TB1<TB2,TA1<TB1,TA1<TB2,TA2<=TB1,TA2<TB2],[TA1<TA2,TB1<TB2,TA1<TB1],L).
```

First normalize inequalities:

- if `A > B` substitute to `B < A`; and
- if `A >= B` substitute to `B <= A`.

What you then can do, is blow up the assumptions:

- if `A<B` and `B<C`, then add `A<C`;
- if `A<=B` and `B<=C`, then add `A<C`;
- if `A<B` and `B<C`, then add `A<C`; and
- if `A<=B` and `B<=C`, then add `A<=C`.

Finally you remove discovered relations from the list of constraints. Thus:

- remove `A <= B` if `A <= B` is given;
- remove `A <= B` if `A < B` is given;
- remove `A < B` if `A < B` is given; and
- substitute `A <= B` in `A=B` if `A < B` is given.

Finally remove redundant constraints:

- `A<B` and `A<B` to `A<B`;
- `A<=B` and `A<=B` to `A<=B`;
- `A<B` and `A<=B` to `A<B`; and (by @Patrick J. S.)
- `A<=B` and `B<=A` to `A=B`.

Comment: Could you elaborate your third block (the remove/substitute one)? I'm not sure if there are errors, or if I just don't understand it. especially the second and last list items seem contradictory to me. Also there could be an additional "substitute `A=B` for `A<=B` and `B<=A` are given.

Comment: @PatrickJ.S.: added your substitution, i dont see why? You trade of two constraints for one, so there is not much contradiction I guess?

Comment: Thanks, got it now, based on where you put that clause. Am not sure what I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you can do with SWI-Prolog and CHR :

```
:- use_module(library(chr)).

:- op(700,xfx,before).

:- chr_constraint before/2, t/2, clean/0.

% X before Y means variable X is less-or-equal to variable Y
% 
transitivity @ X before Y, Y before Z ==> X \= Y, Y \= Z | X before Z.
idempotence  @ X before Y \ X before Y <=> true.

irreflexivity @ t(N,_) before t(M, _), t(M,_) before t(N, _) <=> fail.

generation @ t(N,X) before t(M, M1) ==> member(X, [1,2]),
                                  member(Y, [1,2]),
                                  X \= Y,
                                  M \= N | t(N,Y) before t(M, M1).

generation @ t(N,N1) before t(M, X) ==> member(X, [1,2]),
                                  member(Y, [1,2]),
                                  X \= Y,
                                  M \= N | t(N,N1) before t(M, Y).

% if task N is before task M keep only relevant before
clean_1 @ t(N,N1) before t(M,M1) \ t(N,N2) before t(M,M2) <=> N2 < N1, M1 =< M2 | true.
clean_1 @ t(N,N1) before t(M,M1) \ t(N,N2) before t(M,M2) <=> N2 =< N1, M1 < M2 | true.

%if task N is before task M,  suppress unnecessary t(N, _) before t(N,_)
clean_2 @ t(N, _) before t(M,_)\ t(N, _) before t(N, _) <=> N \= M | true.

% if task N is before task M suppress unnecessary t(M, _) before t(M,_)
clean_3 @ t(N, _) before t(M,_)\ t(M, _) before t(M, _) <=> N \= M  | true.

% if tasks are chained, suppress unnecessary t(First,_) before t(Last,_)
clean_4 @ t(N,_) before t(M,_), t(M,_) before t(P,_) \ t(N,_)  before t(P,_) <=> N \= M, N \= P, M \= P
                                         | true.

% when program is finished clear the set of constraints
clean @ clean \ _ before _  <=> true.
clean @ true \ clean <=> true.


go :-
        % ta1 < ta2
    t(1,1) before t(1,2),
    % tb1 < tb2
    t(2,1) before t(2,2),
    % ta1 < tb1
    t(1,1) before t(2,1),
    % ta1 < tb2
    t(1,1) before t(2,2),
    % ta2 <= tb1
    t(1,2) before t(2,1),
    % ta2 < tb2
    t(1,2) before t(2,2),
    setof(X before Y, find_chr_constraint(X before Y) , Lt),
    writeln(Lt),
    clean.
```

You get :

```
 ?- go.
[t(1,2)before t(2,1)]
true ;
false.
```